# Cauchy Integral Theorem with $f(z)=e^{z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, parametrization, line-integrals, cauchy-integral-formula

I have $z(t)=t(1-t)e^t + \cos(2 \pi \cdot t^3)i$ with $0 \le  t  \le 1$ and need to evaluate the line integral of $e^{z^2}$.

I know that the endpoints are $z(0)=z(1)=0+i$, so the line is a closed curve. I also know that $e^{z^2}$ is an analytic function, so we can use Cauchy's integral formula here.

I have a decent understanding of Cauchy's, but still kind of confused. Doesn't it make us "pick" a point that lies inside the curve (since the denominator is $(z-a)$). How am I supposed to pick a point within this curve for this problem? It feels fairly arbitrary. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Cauchy's Integral Theorem* says that if $f$ is analytic on a simply connected domain $D$ and $\gamma$ is a closed, rectifiable curve in $D$ then

$$ \oint_\gamma f = 0. $$

*Cauchy's Integral Formula* says that under the same hypotheses **and if $\pmb\gamma$ winds around $\pmb a$ once counterclockwise**, then

$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z - a} dz = f(a). $$

The point being that there are two theorems which are related but do different things for you.

One could also say
$$ \frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{(z - a)^{n+1}} dz = f^{(n)}(a). $$
The Integral Theorem is with $n = -1$ (almost; you need to get rid of the $n!$ in this case) and the Integral Formula is with $n = 0$.

Comment: Thanks! This helps a bit with that understanding. So would I be correct in believing we should use Cauchy's Formula for this problem? It seems to be the right way to go but the integral lacks the (z-a) denominator here

Comment: @Anthony You should use the first version (the integral theorem) that doesn't have a denominator.

Comment: Ah thank you! It just clicked for me right now